# Registering clients with Eureka in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to set up a microservices architecture in AWS using beanstalk. I'm using a springboot example which uses a Eureka registration service to let services find other services. This all runs locally fine but i'm now trying to put it on AWS and i've run into a blocker with IP addresses with the registered clients. 
Each service starts up correctly and registers with Eureka. I can access each service individually by hitting it's URL directly. However, when I try to send a request from one service to another I get:

```
504 Gateway Time-out
nginx/1.10.3
```

in Eureka the services are registered but I can't access the urls that they are registered with:

```
Application AMIs    Availability Zones  Status     General Info
ACCOUNTS-SERVICE    n/a (1) (1) UP (1) - ip-xxxx.eu-west-2.compute.internal:accounts-service:5000
ITEMS-SERVICE   n/a (1) (1) UP (1) - ip-xxxx.eu-west-2.compute.internal:items-service:5000
WEB-SERVICE n/a (1) (1) UP (1) - ip-xxxx.eu-west-2.compute.internal:web-service:5000
```

I'm guessing that these urls are private to the individual services as each service is it's own separate beanstalk application. But that might be a complete red herring.

I'm missing a piece of the config puzzle, can anyone could point me in the right direction?

Comment: Are you opening up the security groups assigned to each Elastic Beanstalk app to allow incoming requests from the other apps?

Comment: That was exactly it. Just went into EC2 dashboard and added the inbound port for each microservice. Thank you